# Haskell Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Control.Monad.Logger.LoggingT IO’

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with compile haskell program. Code should make simple rest api with persistance. I use postgres as database engine. When I type `stack build` I gets an error

```
 • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Control.Monad.Logger.LoggingT IO’
      Expected type: Control.Monad.Logger.LoggingT IO ()
        Actual type: IO ()
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘Db.withPostgresqlPool connStr 10
           $ \ pool
               -> do runDB pool $ Db.runMigration migrateAll
                     scotty 5001 $ do ...’
      In the expression:
        runStderrLoggingT
          $ Db.withPostgresqlPool connStr 10
              $ \ pool
                  -> do runDB pool $ Db.runMigration migrateAll
                        scotty 5001 $ do ...
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = runStderrLoggingT
                $ Db.withPostgresqlPool connStr 10
                    $ \ pool
                        -> do runDB pool $ Db.runMigration migrateAll
                              ....
   |
20 | main = runStderrLoggingT $ Db.withPostgresqlPool connStr 10 $ \pool -> do
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...


--  While building custom Setup.hs for package App-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/lukasz/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build exe:App --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I don't known why.

My code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main where

import           Control.Monad.IO.Class               (liftIO)

import           Network.HTTP.Types
import           Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger
import           Network.Wai.Middleware.Static
import           Web.Scotty
import           Control.Monad.Logger    (runStderrLoggingT)

import qualified Database.Persist.Postgresql          as Db

import           Models
import           ModelsJson

main :: IO()
main = runStderrLoggingT $ Db.withPostgresqlPool connStr 10 $ \pool -> do

  -- Migrate database
  runDB pool $ Db.runMigration migrateAll

  -- Start server
  scotty 5001 $ do

    middleware logStdoutDev

    -- * Static content middleware
    --middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "public")

    get "/" $
      html $ "<h1>Backend API server (haskell Scotty)</h1>"

    -- * CRUD

    get "/api/users" $ do
      (users :: [Db.Entity User]) <-
        liftIO $ runDB pool $ Db.selectList [] []
      json users

    post "/api/users" $ do
      (user :: User) <- jsonData
      uid <- liftIO $ runDB pool $ Db.insert user
      json $ Db.Entity uid user


connStr :: Db.ConnectionString
connStr =  "host=localhost dbname=road_free_development user=cidevant password='' port=5432"

runDB :: Db.ConnectionPool ->  Db.SqlPersistM a -> IO a
runDB = flip Db.runSqlPersistMPool
```

I get this code from this source https://gist.github.com/konstantinwebarchitect/11231173

Can anyone help me? I'm new in haskell.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something inside the big lambda forces it to be of type `IO a` instead of the correct `LoggerT IO a`, which in turn forces result if `Db.with...` be of `IO a` type.

It looks like the reason is in the `runDb` call, it should be wrapped into `liftIO` like in other places of your code, but I cannot verify it now.